# Primefaces InputMask optional digits

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working on a small Project using `Primefaces`.

I'm trying to display value from my database with special formation
I store a String in my database which Looks like this `40;99;1;0;0;12`
These are six different numbers seperated with a `;`and they have a range between 0-99.

I want to display this value in an InputMask to make sure that the user doesn't forget the `;`.
Now I have a problem with the format.

I'm using this

`<p:inputMask id="myID" placeholder="Value" value="#{myClass.value}" mask="9?9;99;99;99;99;99"/>`

I'm trying to say that the mask contains six "fields" for a number input and each field can contain a number between 1-99.

The problem is if the user writes the input as this `30;10;0_;0_;0_;4_`Primefaces converts it to `30;10;00;04;__;_`

Is there a good way to let the mask know that it can be a number with one or two digits?
Or is there a way to say, if input has just one digit put a 0 first

Comment: in jquery plugin that uses the same syntax, you can define `[9]` but in primefaces that is not rendered correctly. it doesnt understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this solution fits your needs, but you can define a custom mask

```
$.mask.definitions['h'] = "[0-9]{0,1}";
$("#form\\:your_input_mask_id").mask("hh;hh;hh;hh;hh;hh");
```

in your `document.ready` function. This will leave the `_` character as is, but I guess you can handle it in your code when splitting the string and handling each part. I've put form\: because you generally put these inputs inside a form with `id` form. Change accordingly!

This has the downside though, that if you dont enter something, it will also validate, regardless of not being between 1 and 99.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but it didn't worked. I think it can't find the element. $("#myForm:myElementID").mask("hh;hh;hh;hh;hh;hh");

Comment: check in your html code, that your element has the correct id and also check that this javascript is actually running without any exceptions. please also note that you need the \\ before the : in order for the id to be "escaped" and understood.

Comment: Just one more. I've forgot to say that it's inside a Panel & panegrid. Do I Need to give theme also an ID and how do I call them?

Comment: you must see the generated id of your component. if it generates a random id, then you have to give an id to its parent components too.

Comment: Now it works like 50% it sets the mask correctly but it's still possible to enter letters or other digits rather than numbers. how can I fix that

Comment: `[0-9]{0,1}` means at most one digit. so it cant accept any other character.

Comment: Like I told you it accept any character I type and I used the jquery as your example

Comment: it seems that due to 0 for occurences at the regex, the plugin allows user to enter anything else as character.